# I am not able to convince myself with the gauss law, explain why the situation below shouldn't have non-zero flux?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

I have drawn an image of a spherical surface and positive charge outside it. As the positive charge is outside the sphere the electric field incident at every small surface is different from the other therefore shouldn't there be non-zero electric field through the surface?

[image: this image shows the above mentioned statements in detail.]

Comment: What I would recommend you to do is drawing multiple concentric circles around your point charge that intersect with the sphere and convince yourself that stronger electric field enters a smaller fraction of the closer side of the sphere while weaker electric field lines exit from a larger area of the sphere on its farther side.

Comment: Minor details: 1. $\phi = \int \vec E \cdot d \vec A$ and not $EA cos \theta$.
2. Total flux would be $\phi _1 + \phi _2$ and not $\phi_1-\phi_2$.

Comment: Think of the field rays in particular. Think of them as actual rays. Obviously, if nothing is stopping (absorbing) them inside, then they will necessarily pass through. Any entering ray will necessarily also leave again later on. Meaning, all ingoing flux equals all outgoing flux. The net flux is zero.

Comment: @Steeven,but that would only be correct if field lines are from an uniform electric field.

Comment: Is the sphere from conducting material?

Comment: @gontusandeep No. Regardless of where these field lines come from, if they enter they must also leave. You can think of them very intuitively as rays of light. Og maybe as sprays of water yets. They don't stop moving if nothing stops them. So if they enter the defined spherical volume, then they also leave it again through some other point. This is not about the shape of the ray pattern; this intuitive idea holds true for a single ray regardless of others being present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope these two diagrams may help you.In first case I have assumed the sphere in a  uniform field and in other case the sphere is in non uniform field due to a point charge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyFUg.jpg)[image]